# Is there a way to syntax highlight an If - End If statement in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, syntax-highlighting

I am trying to read through some code and it would be helpful if the editor in VS 2008 would highlight the **If** statement by using the cursor and double clicking the **End If** statement (or something like that).

I believe I could do something like this in Java using Eclipse - it was very good at highlighting a code block by clicking next to one of the curly braces.

Anyone know how to do this kind of thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible by default in regular pure Visual Studio installation - statement blocks are not highlighted in VB.NET.

There are many text-highlighting plugins (like Visual Assist X etc.) some of them are free, maybe some of them provide this feature.

I use Expression Studio 3, in the code editor all the bloks have a visible indentation, I wish this could be in VS too...

I think that VS 2010 has implemented it so don't waste time on creating your own plug-in (unless you do it for fun...).